# Is there any compiler simulator for mobile phones?

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-construction, mobile-phones

I was wondering if there exists an application for mobile phones(any platform) that simulates compiler, validates syntax?
 It would be nice to have one the phone:) Particularly I am looking something for C# or C++(like gcc).

It does not have to generate any output code, just the front-end part(lexilal, syntax analysis...)

Comment: Maybe there's a website syntax validator for some languages out there..

Comment: You should learn about programming for mobile devices in general. Choose a platform that suits you (Android, iOS, Symbian) and learn what tools are used on that platform.

Comment: I'm not asking how to create application for mobile phones but for an application for mobile phone that simulates compiler.

Comment: @A. Nosal: Please rewrite the first sentence of your question. It's quite misleading.

Comment: gcc -E should be sufficient, given you are using the correct toolchain. Not sure if you can fit GCC on a phone though  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try online compilers that work through web browsers, such as [Compilr.com](http://compilr.com).

Comment: This site probably won't work on mobile but I will search in that direction (though internet connection is needed).

Answer (score 0):

Many mobile phones have SDKs, these will include all the tools that you need to develop on that particular device.
[Symbian](http://www.symbian.org) and [Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) are two that spring to mind.